# I cannot assign a value to a long from settings in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to set a long variable to the value of Properties.Settings.
Here is the code I use:

```
    private void SaveGame()
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Points = points;
        Properties.Settings.Default.U1 = Upgrade1Amount;
        Properties.Settings.Default.U2 = Upgrade2Amount;
        Properties.Settings.Default.U3 = Upgrade3Amount;
        Properties.Settings.Default.U4 = Upgrade4Amount;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

The function above is called every second using the stopwatch component:

```
                    private void gameSpeedTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        points += 1 * Upgrade1Amount;
        points += 150 * Upgrade2Amount;
        points += 25000 * Upgrade3Amount;
        points += 5000000 * Upgrade4Amount;
        UpdatePointAmount();
        SaveGame();
    }
```

And I am also trying to write it after the variables have been assigned:

```
    private void LoadGame()
    {
        points = Properties.Settings.Default.Points;
        Upgrade1Amount = Properties.Settings.Default.U1;
        Upgrade2Amount = Properties.Settings.Default.U2;
        Upgrade3Amount = Properties.Settings.Default.U3;
        Upgrade4Amount = Properties.Settings.Default.U4;
        UpdatePointAmount();
    }
```

The function above is called once when the form opens:

```
public GameController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UpdatePointAmount();
        LoadGame();
        buttonClick = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.pickupCoin);
        UpgradeClick = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.pickupCoin1);
        gameSpeedTimer.Start();
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of the settings:
[The settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyRhL.png)

App.config:

```
     <Clicker.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Points" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="U1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="U2" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="U3" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="U4" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1</value>
        </setting>
    </Clicker.Properties.Settings>
```

The problem is that the value of the variable doesn't get assigned, nor do the settings get overwritten.

Comment: Can you give some context to this code? E.g., when / where is it run? Is the points value assigned and saved (hence, it's persisted on a second run)? If you open the `user.config` file, what do you see inside it?

Comment: @Jimi The first part is ran after the form loads and the second part is ran every second.

Comment: I meant, update your question and add the method where that code is taken from and, eventually, what calls that method and when / where -- You haven't provided details in relation to the other questions -- What `App.config` contains is not relevant (you wouldn't be able to use any of the values in `Properties.Settings.Default`), I've asked you to check what **`user.config`** contains. Also, are you calling any other method of `Properties.Settings.Default`? As `Upgrade()`, `Reset()`, `Reload()`...

Comment: I have fixed it, no idea why it is fixed but yeah. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by initializing the SaveGame() function in the gameSpeedTimer_Tick() instead of UpdatePointAmount(), I have no idea why that worked, but it works now.